# The operation was canceled .net

Tags: .net

I have a microservices project developed in .net 3.1, I have my various services and my gateways to connect to them, 1 in 1 of my services I upload an XML file and extract the information it contains, however some of them bring a lot of information and arrive a point where the project throws the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMxa9.png)

The project does not stop and if it concludes with the loading of information both from the XML with too much information and from the others, however, how could I avoid this error:

I attach the method with which I call the GATEWAY.

```
 public async Task<int> CreateFactura([FromForm] CFDICreateCommand factura)
 {
     var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.Anio.ToString()), "Anio");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.InmuebleId.ToString()), "InmuebleId");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.FacturacionId.ToString()), "FacturacionId");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.Mes.ToString()), "Mes");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.UsuarioId.ToString()), "UsuarioId");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.Inmueble.ToString()), "Inmueble");
     formContent.Add(new StringContent(factura.TipoFacturacion.ToString()), "TipoFacturacion");
     var fileXMLContent = new StreamContent(factura.XML.OpenReadStream());
     fileXMLContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(factura.XML.ContentType);
     formContent.Add(fileXMLContent, name: "XML", factura.XML.FileName);
     if (factura.PDF != null)
     {
         var filePDFContent = new StreamContent(factura.PDF.OpenReadStream());
         filePDFContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(factura.PDF.ContentType);
         formContent.Add(filePDFContent, name: "PDF", factura.PDF.FileName);
     }

     var request = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_apiGatewayUrl}mensajeria/cfdi/createFactura", formContent);
     request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(
         await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
         new JsonSerializerOptions
         {
             PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
         }
     );
 }
```

I would be very grateful if you could please help me

I have investigated and found that a timeout should be used with http client but it has not been implemented.

I hope you can support me.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means the request timed out. `HttpClient` has a [timeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0) that defaults to 100 seconds.

Now as for why your request would be taking more than 100 seconds, I don’t know. Regardless, you pretty much always want to handle any `OperationCancelledException` thrown by an HTTP request, since network blips are a thing.

```cs
// Could make the retry count configurable.
var retries = 5;

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        // Make your HTTP request here.
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException) when (retries-- > 0)
    {
        // Could add some logging and/or make the sleep configurable.
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

If you're using HTTP client factory, you can also [configure it to do this for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support friend, if it's not too much trouble, which section of the code that I inserted as an example in the question would include the TimeWait parameter, I would greatly appreciate it if you would please advise me.

Comment: You could add `_httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);` before you make the request. It's probably better to do it as part of the initialization of your client, which is not included in your code.